# JavaScript pull data from HTML table cell to input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table

I have an HTML page. On the page I have a `table` with 8 columns and 56 rows and an input (number).

Whichever cell I click, I want it to transfer the number in it into the `input`. How can I do that?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Could you please add the HTML to the question so we can see what structure you're working with in order to give you an accurate answer. That said, if you're using jQuery you simply need the [`on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on), [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest), [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find) and [`val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val) methods.

Comment: What have you tried? Which part of the problem are you having a problem with? You need to listen for an event use the event to read the value and update the input. Can you add your code with specific question?

Comment: I can't add code as I'm typing from my mobile phone right now, I will add it as soon as possible.  A single page that I wrote with notped.  I don't know how to use jq, mostly copy paste.  I am using JavaScript functions.  Honestly, I don't know what kind of structure I'm using.  I created a table with html codes.  Again, I added an input with the html code.  I want to add the cell content I clicked to the input.value with a JavaScript function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const myInput = document.querySelector('#myInput');
const cells = document.querySelectorAll('#myTable tr td');

cells.forEach(el => 
    el.addEventListener('click', (e) => myInput.value = e.currentTarget.innerText)
);
```

This is assuming html like the following:

```html
<input type="text" id="myInput" value="" />
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Update (Breakdown of what we are doing above):

All we are doing is we are keeping things really simple.  We create a selector for the elements we're after.   Given there are multiple table cells, we use `querySelectorAll` which will return an array of elements.

We then just loop over all these elements and add a `click` event listener to each of them.   The listener grabs the innerText of the cell and just sets it to the targeted input box.

This could be expanded on however you want.  Chose to keep this simple and just do what was being asked.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, I will try it as soon as possible and let you know.

Comment: Hi Jonathon, Thank you very much again, everything works as I want. you solved the problem.
If you have time, I would like you to explain the working logic of this code.

Comment: Sure I'll add it to the description to help out